# Join Collection with other table to get title from another table

Tags: magento-1.8, collection

I have two table which are as below. I would like to match title based on first table and select title form another table for all the first table.

My code for get this resul is

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('specificationvalues/specificationvalues')->getCollection();
  $collection->getSelect()->join(array('ot' =>'specificationoptions'),"main_table.options = ot.specificationoptions_id",array('optiontitle' =>'ot.title'))
```

But it gives only 4 records

Table Structure.

```
    Main Table

specificationvalue

specificatinovalue_id   title       options
1                       value1        1
2                       value2        2  
3                       value3        2  
4                       value4        3  
5                       value5        3  
6                       value6        4  
7                       value7        4  
8                       value8        4  
9                       value9        4 
10                      value10       4  

Join Table

specificatinooptions

specificationoptions_id   title
1           option1
2           option2
3           option3
4           option4


Result should be

specificatinovalue_id   title       optiontitle
1                       value1        option1
2                       value2        option2  
3                       value3        option2  
4                       value4        option3  
5                       value5        option3  
6                       value6        option4  
7                       value7        option4 
8                       value8        option4  
9                       value9        option4 
10                      value10       option4
```

Comment: try leftjoin instead of join

Comment: No luck using joinLeft

Comment: Try with echoing your query by `echo $collection->getSelect()` and check. Or paste your query here in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$collection =   Mage::getModel('specificationvalues/specificationvalues')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('ot' =>'specificationoptions'),"main_table.options = ot.specificationoptions_id",array('optiontitle' =>'ot.title'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('specificationvalues/specificationvalues')->getCollection()->joinField('optiontitle', 
   'specificationoptions', 
   'title', 
   'specificationoptions_id=options', 
   array('title'=>array('neq' => '')),
   'left'
);
```

Comment: ` Call to undefined method Test_Specificationvalues_Model_Mysql4_Specificationvalues_Collection::joinField()` Errorr :(